# Parent div expanding larger than child img node

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex item, `image-container`, that contains an image:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image" src="image.jpg"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want `image-container` and `image` to have equal width and height but I don't want their height to exceed the height of the window so I tried the following CSS:

```
html,body,#root {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;

  background-color: blue;
}
```

The problem is `image-container` has a width that is much larger than `image`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jimby/pen/gOqdrvx)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is setting the image container to inline-block and the image to block, optionally set a width to the image:

```
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 250px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh0sewbg/6/)

Comment: I specified that I want `image-container` and `image` to have the same height as the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `min-height: 0;` from `.image-container`
and it will be fixed

Comment: That changes the height of the image which I specified I didn't want to do.

Comment: @Jimmy If you want to add height for the image give it to the img element not the container.
img {
  height: 200px;
}

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. I want the height to be dynamic. I don't want to set it to a fixed height.

Comment: @Jimmy it's dynamic by default you don't need to add the min-height property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an image too big, if it is your case this code may help you

```
body,
html,
#root {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This styling still results in `image-container` having a width that is much larger than `image`.

Comment: Can you send me an screenshot, I try it in Chrome and Edge and works

Answer (score 0):

Please update your css code with this one;

```
html,body,#root {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  min-height:0;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  background-color: blue;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In this updated css code I have added `box-sizing: border-box;` to reset the document. Added `min-height:0` as you are using `flex-direction:column;` to container and removed few unused css property over here and finally `.image-container` code updated and also add some css with `<img>` tag so that it fits with its parent.

It will work definitely.

Comment: This changes the height of the image which I specified I didn't want to do.

Comment: You can change the width and height using attribute. Moreover it is more viable/flexible to set these to default so that it can be used for larger applications otherwise it may disturb layout.